# How to use chromeoption and desirecapabilities in Jmeter Webdriver sampler?

Tags: selenium, automation, jmeter, webdriver

I am using Jmeter webdriver sampler with chrome-browser. I need to use chromeoption and desire capability in jmeter. How to I code to use those options.

example code which I want to use can be this.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments(new String[] {"window-size=12000,10000"});
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
```

Can someone help in this.

Comment: Hi Deepak, did you get any solution? We too have same issue and needs to handle in Jmeter selenium webdriver. Please share if any thing worked. Thanks.

Comment: Not yet got the solution because the driver will be created with default desired capabilities in jmeter web driver samplers. But you can use other coding options options in jmeter where you can only create the driver and before you can set capability.

Comment: Can you tell me or ask the question relatively with more specification, me or some other can help you

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had posted similar query and got working solutions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54408036/jsr233-sampler-with-java-to-work-with-selenium-webdriver-javax-script-scriptexc   though facing issues while handling elements (most of the cases no such elements issues, trying to resolve)

Comment: Yes it is common because you are trying to run in multiple systems/browsers. if it runs in one system it may fail in another. So you have to use some some proper wait statements where ever required and don't hesitate to ask me on any help on this

Comment: Thanks a lot Deepak for extending help, sure will post query if facing any issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking into [ChromeDriverConfig.java](https://github.com/undera/jmeter-plugins/blob/master/plugins/webdriver/src/main/java/com/googlecode/jmeter/plugins/webdriver/config/ChromeDriverConfig.java)  it isn't something you can currently control with the [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/) so the options are in:

1. Patch `ChromeDriverConfig` source code and amend initialization of the ChromeOptions and DesiredCapabilities according to your needs. Once done you will need to re-build the plugin and put it to "lib/ext" folder of your JMeter installation.
2. Switch to [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) where you will have full control of the WebDriver instance (however you will need to take care about starting and stopping it, using free ports, etc.). The recommended language for using with JSR223 Sampler is [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following sample taken from [selenium closed issue](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/7043)

> ```
> options.ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
> options.AddArgument("--start-maximized");
>
> // You can cast the ICapabilities object returned by ToCapabilities()
> // as DesiredCapabilities. Future .NET bindings releases will likely
> // have a copy constructor for this, but this will do for now.
> DesiredCapabilities caps = options.ToCapabilities() as DesiredCapabilities;
> caps.SetCapability("platform", "VISTA");
> caps.SetCapability("version", "{whatever}"";
> IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("{grid location}",
> ```