# When replacing selenium jars with latest version under JMeter lib folder 'ConversionException' is thrown

Tags: selenium, jmeter, performance-testing, blazemeter

I am working with JMeter and Selenium. Installed the plugins manager and via that, installed web-driver sampler. When I look into lib folder, I found the selenium jars version are 2.52.0 which is much older. I can able to work with that without any issues. But the real problem is:

Using Maven, I updated all the selenium jars to 3.9.1 version and its dependant jars like guava, gson, commons, etc.

Now, when I open the jmx files with WebDriver sampler and driver configs, I receive below error.

[image]

Using maven, I mean, I downloaded all the jars from maven repo manually and pasted into JMeter lib folder.

Please help me to work with latest Selenium drivers in JMeter.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to use WebDriver Sampler plugin with Selenium 3.9.1 as it explicitly relies on [SessionNotFoundException](https://github.com/undera/jmeter-plugins/blob/e8b2285c678b1de49bf8e8a1b72de69bf3ceb6a6/plugins/webdriver/src/main/java/com/googlecode/jmeter/plugins/webdriver/config/WebDriverConfig.java#L18) class which has been removed in the latest Selenium libraries.

So the options are in:

1. Use WebDriver Sampler with browser version(s) supported by Selenium 2.52.0
2. Reach out to WebDriver Sampler plugin developers and/or maintainers at [jmeter-plugins](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jmeter-plugins) forum to check whether it is planned to update Selenium libraries and if yes - when. You can also update WebDriver Sampler source code by yourself and send pull request to the plugin maintainer.
3. Switch to [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) language instead. Apart from being able to use latest libraries you will have full control of the WebDriver instance using [DesiredCapabilities](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities) at full instead of limited subset exposed via *Driver Config elements.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Could you please explain "full control of the WebDriver instance using DesiredCapabilities" ?? where can I define the capabilities in Web driver sampler ?. I currenlty edited the InternetExplorerDriverConfig.class file and added some more capabilities under Capabilities createCapabilities() method. But it doesnt work for me.

Comment: Hi Dmitri, here in this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49239525/how-to-use-chromeoption-and-desirecapabilities-in-jmeter-webdriver-sampler), you have told about re-building the Plugin. Please tell me how to re-build that after the patch.

Comment: `mvn package` from the root of jmeter-plugins cloned repository